Issue with subd+creases/bevels workflow
It is not the first time I encounter it, but I am sick of it enough to ask for advice. I have a number of surfaces, where I want smooth geometry to convert to sharp one. I am using creases or bevels, but this is what I run into:
example 1: I need this part to be sharp and the outside to be smooth...

...But outer smooth part goes through corner vertices and make weird inverted geometry:

Another example of this issue:

Loopcuts does not help. There are multiple ways to butcher the geometry and make the problem literally smaller, but it still does that (for example, beveling these corner diagonal edges makes it so this type of overlap occurs on a smaller scale on each individual turn). How do I get around this without retopoing whole mesh?

It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

I agree with @RickT here. Sure, we can try to build some geometry that might or might not result in the same issues, but as long as it is not the same our solutions might work on our examples but not on yours.

are these blue lines Bevel Weights? Sometimes you need to manually bevel to have a good result, as Rick says, please share an example
